# RDP app for Android

Tags: android, open-source, remote-desktop

I'm looking for an RDP app for android that:

- Is FOSS
- Can connect to a xrdp server
- Can send all the characters on my (virtual) keyboard
- Has all mouse buttons (left, middle and right)
- Has a mouse that acts like Microsoft's RDP app
- Can zoom in and out
- Supports landscape and portrait mode
- Supports 32-bit colors

Nice to have:

- Support for VNC, SSH and SFTP

Comment: While waiting for good recommendations: be welcome taking a look at my app list to [Remote control your Windows PC](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controlpc#group_656). I'm not using any such app (have no Windows machine), so i cannot tell which app meets your requirements. But the list narrows down candidates :)

Comment: +Izzy It's meant for remote controlling my Linux PC (I don't have a Windows PC either), xrdp is a RDP server for Linux…

Comment: Same page, also different section then :) I've sorted RDP in the Windows section, as that's where it's mostly used. I'm aware it's used elsewhere, too (e.g. VMWare/VirtualBox implements this AFAIK) – but I have to place it somewhere while keeping the structure ;)